# Indoor camera with night vision and no Internet access

Tags: video-camera, home-security

I am looking for an indoor camera with the following requirements:

- night vision with infrared  (i.e. can see in a 100% dark room)
- no Internet access needed
- save video (e.g. on an SD card)
- at least 480p
- doesn't need to have a microphone but it is ok if it has one

I don't have a hard threshold on the price but below 100 USD sounds reasonable.

My use case: I am performing a study on sleep positions with several human subjects. Understandably, they want privacy, which an Internet access cannot guarantee.

---

I have found many cameras satisfying all requirements except the no Internet requirement, e.g.:

- [YI Dome Camera Pan/Tilt/Zoom Wireless IP Security Surveillance System 720p HD Night Vision (US Edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CW4BG4K)
- [FDT 720P HD WiFi Pan/Tilt IP Camera](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01GF5M42A)
- [Zmodo 720p HD WiFi Wireless Smart Security Camera Two-Way Audio](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01HH3UWU0)

Related but different: [Security camera that doesn't use a third party](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2670/40)

Answer (score 2):

I found a *dash cam* that fits your requirements:

[AUKEY Dash Cam, Full HD 1080P, 170° Wide Angle Lens, Night Vision, Car Dashboard Camera](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M592J9C)

It sells for $90 on Amazon.com

---

- **Supports recording resolutions of: 1080p 30fps, 720p 30/60fps, 480p**
- **No wifi or internet connection**
- **Saves to a MicroSD card (up to 128GB)**
- **Good night vision capaiblity (according to product description and "Verified Purchase" reviews)**
- **Below 100 USD (90 USD)**
- Can record continuously (loop/overwrite) or do timelapses
- Has a microphone
- Wide FOV (170 degrees)
- Screws on to a suction cup or adhesive mount (since it is a dash cam)

---

It is only USB powered, meaning that you might need a USB power brick like 
[this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LCDJ7LG). Also, if you want to record in 1080p for 10 or so hours, I would recommend a SD card with a capacity of at least 64GB.

Comment: Thanks, I think for dashcams night vision means at night but not in a ~100% dark environment. So I doubt it would work for my use case (video of people sleeping in a dark room).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt No problem, in that case, I assume you're talking about infrared capability rather than low light sensitivity?

Comment: Correct, looking for infrared. I edited the question to make it clearer.